# Is this FTP transfer secure? Do I need a new FTP client?

Tags: encryption, passwords

I am using a very old FTP client.  I have checked the "secure (SSL)" box in the connection editor.  As far as I know, the server supports explicit FTPS but not implicit FTPS or SFTP.

When I log in and do a transfer, I see an "AUTH SSL" command, but no PBSZ or PROT lines.  Here is a sample:

```
Finding Host ftp.softronics.ch ...
Connecting to 62.2.182.131:21
Connected to 62.2.182.131:21 in 0.087, Waiting for Server Response
220 ProFTPD 1.3.3a Server (Softronics FTP) [62.2.182.131]
Host type (1): Automatic detect
AUTH SSL
234 AUTH SSL successful
USER <DELETED>
331 Password required for <DELETED>
PASS (hidden)
230-8278412.12 KB used - authorized: 15728640.00 KB
230 User <DELETED> logged in
SYST
215 UNIX Type: L8
Host type (2): UNIX (standard)
FEAT
211-Features:
 XSHA256
 MDTM
 MFMT
 TVFS
 AUTH TLS
 UTF8
 MFF modify;UNIX.group;UNIX.mode;
 MLST modify*;perm*;size*;type*;unique*;UNIX.group*;UNIX.mode*;UNIX.owner*;
 XSHA1
 PBSZ
 PROT
 SITE MKDIR
 SITE RMDIR
 SITE UTIME
 LANG bg-BG;ko-KR.UTF-8;ko-KR;en-US;zh-TW;fr-FR;ja-JP.UTF-8;ja-JP;zh-CN
 SITE SYMLINK
 REST STREAM
 XCRC
 XMD5
 SIZE
211 End
PWD
257 "/" is the current directory
CWD /Backups
250 CWD command successful
/Backups  loaded from [Directory Listing Cache]DIR51BB.tmp
Starting request
TYPE A
200 Type set to A
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (62,2,182,131,230,178).
connecting data channel to 62.2.182.131:59058
data channel connected to 62.2.182.131:59058
STOR avgsugarPrint.csv
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for avgsugarPrint.csv
transferred 4392 bytes in < 0.001 seconds, 34312.500 Kbps ( 4289.063 KBps), transfer succeeded.
226 Transfer complete
Transfer request completed with status: Finished
PWD
257 "/Backups" is the current directory
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (62,2,182,131,216,236).
connecting data channel to 62.2.182.131:55532
data channel connected to 62.2.182.131:55532
LIST
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for file list
transferred 11296 bytes in 0.270 seconds, 326.833 Kbps ( 40.854 KBps), transfer succeeded.
QUIT
221 Goodbye.
```

What is happening here, as far as security goes?  Is it good enough?  Are the username and password being sent encrypted?

Thanks.

D.

Comment: You could use a network profiler to determine what is visible on the network. This will give some insight from another angle.

Answer (score 2):

Username and password are protect since the control connection is switched to TLS using `AUTH SSL` before the login credentials are sent. But it is unknown how good they are protected, i.e. if they are protected with a strong or weak cipher and if the servers certificate was checked properly. Especially properly checking the certificate is a well known problem and since the client is old chances are high that no check or nor proper check is done and the connection is thus open to man in the middle attacks.

Apart from that no `PROT` command is issued which means that the data connections (i.e. directory listing, transferred files) are not protected.